# Using Django, updating a model using REGEXP_REPLACE with multiple patterns to match

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, regexp-replace

I've searched and found similar posts but not this specific. I am currently trying to update a models JSON field using `REGEXP_REPLACE`. I want to do it in one query so I want to match multiple patterns and replace them in one call. With my current setup, if I have just one pattern I want to match the code works fine eg. name1, but as soon as I try to match multiple using (name1|name2) it doesn't work.

A small example:
We have a JSON field `information` on a model `Person`. The information field is populated with the following:

```
{"name": "first_name last_name", "description": "Test description", "address": "123 example street"}
```

The code I currently am using to do REGEXP_REPLACE is:

```
find_pattern = r'(name|description)": "(.*?)",'
repl_pattern = r'\1": "filler",'
Cast(
    Case(
        When(
            **{f'information__isnull': False},
            then=Func(
                Cast(information, output_field=CharField()),
                Value(find_pattern),
                Value(repl_pattern),
                Value('g'),
                function='REGEXP_REPLACE',
                output_field=CharField(),
            ),
        ),
        default=None,
    ),
    output_field=JSONField(),
)
```

However this does not work and I can't figure out why. I get the following error:

```
django.db.utils.DataError: invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL:  The input string ended unexpectedly.
```

Any help/ideas would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason why you do this at the database side? Why not just process this at the Python/Django layer. Using regexes and text processing on structured data is often not a good idea.

Comment: Another question is what you want to do, just inject `filler` as value for `name` and `description`? Do you want to *update* records? Or just retrieve that as value?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem the reasoning for doing this database side is we're trying to create an anonymised version of our database. So the aim is to update the records to remove any sensitive information.

Comment: but I don't really see how that would really help the cause to do this at the database side, you can just do this with two queries at the Django side, and then the data is "gone" again.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem The idea behind doing it database side and in one query is that it would be faster/more efficient. If we have millions of people and we want to update their information all at once to be anonymised, I don't see how doing that in two queries would be better. What would the two queries be to help me follow along with your train of thought?

Comment: one to fetch all items, one to update all items. With `django-jsonfield` it would be possible to do this in one query, but Django itself now has a JSON field, but it is lacking some of the mechanics `django-jsonfield` had. Perhaps for got reasons.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem So your workflow would be something like: query the database to fetch all items, then process each individual object and their JSONFields, then bulk_update the database with the new anonymised objects? If that is the workflow, do you think it would be faster to just do what I've done above, but iterate over the patterns individually the way that I could get to work? The most amount of patterns would probably be ~3

Comment: no that will not be faster, the question is whether the fastest solution is necessary. That is for example not the aim of Python: Python has been designed under the assumption that developer's time is more expensive than processing time, so instead on focussing on getting the most out of a CPU, make sure people can implement something in a matter of hours. But if you really want to get the most out of the database, using regexes is not the way either.

Comment: In that case it would be something as `UPDATE my_table SET information->>name = 'filler' WHERE information IS NOT NULL`. Which is quite clean and prevents rehashing keys, etc. That is also a query that `django-jsonfield` provided, but Django, which implemented a JSON field currently does not have.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making this problem a lot harder than it should be. Using text processing is often a very bad idea. Especially regexes, regexes are very nice, but people always tend to use these for things that regexes are not made for.

We can just do this at the Django/Python side, with:

```
data = list(
    MyModel.objects.filter(information__isnull=False).only('pk', 'information')
)

for item in data:
    item.information['name'] = item.information['description'] = 'filler'

MyModel.objects.bulk_update(data, fields=('information',))
```

If the amount of data is really huge, we can do this in an iterator-like way:

```
data = []

for item in (
    MyModel.objects.filter(information__isnull=False)
    .only('pk', 'information')
    .iterator(10000)
):
    item.information['name'] = item.information['description'] = 'filler'
    data.append(item)
    if len(data) > 10000:
        MyModel.objects.bulk_update(data, fields=('information',))
        data = []

if data:
    MyModel.objects.bulk_update(data, fields=('information',))
```

here we thus will read and update items in huge chunks of 10'000 records each time for example.